# GridView display duplicate data when page refresh ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

**GridView in ASP.NET:**

```
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel_listview" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <asp:GridView ID="gridview_book_info" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

**Page_Load in VB:**

```
Dim gridview_detail As String
    gridview_detail = "select * from book;"

    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(gridview_detail, cn)
    da.Fill(ds, "book")
    gridview_book_info.DataSource = ds
    gridview_book_info.DataBind()
```

**notes:**

1. `cn` is **MySQL Connection**
2. `ds` is **DataSet**

**Here is my problem:**

When I debugging, Page_Load is triggered and the `gridview` get data from **mysql database** and display it. Example:

```
ABCDE (header)
abcde
```

But when I refresh the page, the gridview will become like this:

```
ABCDE (header)
abcde
abcde
```

It keep duplicating the date from mysql database whenever I refresh page, I have tried:

1. check if **IsPostBack** is true then disable the data retrieving.
2. set datasource equal to Nothing before data retrieving
3. check if the gridview row count is zero

What I wanted to know:

1. Other codes beside IsPostBack to truly check if the page is really refreshing, then I can stop the gridview from retrieve data from mysql database again.
2. Stop GridView from duplicating, since I can't stop user to use refresh button

**I NEED HELP!**

Comment: set `AutoGenerateColumn = false` of the gridview and check. One more thing, what do you mean by _duplicate data_ here. Duplicate columns or rows ?

Comment: after set auto generate column to false my gridview is gone.

Comment: duplicating data means it repeat the process in my Page_Load

Comment: does your gridview has records ?

Comment: when I added gridview in asp.net, it should be blank if I didn't use data adapter and dataset to bind it

Comment: what is `"book"` here ? is it a `stored procedure` ??

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Connect-Bind-GridView-to-MySql-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx). You will get an idea how to use it

Comment: @nad book is a mysql table which i retrieve data from

Comment: @nad I take a look at the link you gave, i tried using data table instead of data set. I have finally prevent it duplicating.

Comment: so is it done or not ?, yes you need to use the keyword _using_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take a look at [Here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Connect-Bind-GridView-to-MySql-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

the original code im using in Page_Load:

```
If Not Me.IsPostBack then
  Dim gridview_detail As String
  gridview_detail = "select * from book;"

  da = New MySqlDataAdapter(gridview_detail, cn)
  da.Fill(ds, "book")
  gridview_book_info.DataSource = ds
  gridview_book_info.DataBind()
End If
```

with the public module i have declare on top :

```
Public ds As New DataSet()
Public connStr As String = "Server=localhost...."
Public cn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
```

I have made changes in Page_Load and it prevent duplicate data in mysql table "book" when i refresh the page:

```
If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
    Using cn
        Using cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM book")
            Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Connection = cn
                da.SelectCommand = cmd
                Using ds As New DataSet()
                    da.Fill(ds)
                    gridview_book_info.DataSource = ds
                    gridview_book_info.DataBind()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End If
```

**So the solution is:**

always use "using" when accessing database.

Please comment below if you have better explanation on this problem about why use "using".

Answer (score 0):

**`IsPostBack`** shows that a post back to the server has occurred, not that the page has refreshed.

Try checking that post back has not happened in the Page load method before databinding

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
  Dim gridview_detail As String
    gridview_detail = "select * from book;"

    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(gridview_detail, cn)
    da.Fill(ds, "book")
    gridview_book_info.DataSource = ds
    gridview_book_info.DataBind()    
End If
```

Comment: it still duplicating the record, i think i found the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the word `using` as it is safe and recommendable to use that.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("yourConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM books")
            Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt
                    GridView1.DataBind()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
 End If  End Sub
```

For the full documentation. Have a look below:-

**http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Connect-Bind-GridView-to-MySql-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx**

Hope that helps you